# Cell overpotential diagrams

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, reference-request, books

Is there anyone who knows a book where I can find a detailed explanation of cell overpotential diagrams, like the ones shown here?

Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what kind of explanation you are looking for, but

[Electrode Dynamics, A. C. Fisher, Oxford Chemistry Press, 1996, ISBN: 019855690X](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/electrode-dynamics-9780198556909?cc=us&lang=en&)

is a great concise explanation of overpotentials among other things.

Answer (score 1):

I have always thought that corrosion textbooks give some of the most concise and enlightening overviews of electrochemistry. One of my favorites is:

> *Corrosion and Surface Chemistry of Metals*, by D. Landolt, EPFL Press, 2007, ISBN:  0849382335

This book will explain to you how to interpret polarization diagrams.  The emphasis, of course, is on corrosion phenomena, but the same type of reasoning applies to any electrochemical system.  The author does a great job of breaking down all the sources of overpotential at an electrode and shows many polarization diagrams along with the discussion.  It really is a great book and I highly recommend it!